# How to prevent XMLStreamWriter writeCharacter method converts \r to &#xd;

Tags: java, xml

How do I prevent from XMLStreamWriter writeCharacter method converts \r to  upon writing to the file.

I have to write the XML formatted already. However, if I use Indentingxmlstreamwriter, it only uses \n instead of \r\n.

Here is the sample code:

---

```
File outputFile = new File(filePath.concat(filename));
FileOutputStream outputFileStream = null;
try {
    outputFileStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}

XMLOutputFactory factory = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();
BufferedOutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(outputFileStream);

try {
    writer = factory.createXMLStreamWriter(outputStream);
    //indwr = new IndentingXMLStreamWriter(writer);
}
catch (XMLStreamException e) {
}


try {

    //writer.setIndentStep("  ");
    writer.writeStartDocument("UTF-8","1.0");

    writer.writeCharacters("\r\n");
    writer.writeStartElement("document");

    writer.writeCharacters("\r\n");
    writer.writeCharacters("  ");

    writer.writeStartElement("data");
    writer.writeAttribute("name", "value");

    writer.writeCharacters("\r\n");
    writer.writeCharacters("    ");

    writer.writeStartElement("data2");
    writer.writeAttribute("name", "value");

    writer.writeEndElement();

    writer.writeCharacters("\r\n");
    writer.writeCharacters("  ");
    writer.writeEndElement();

    writer.writeCharacters("\r\n");
    writer.writeEndElement();

    writer.writeEndDocument();

    writer.flush();
    writer.close();

}
catch (XMLStreamException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

---

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `XmlStreamWriter` is an interface, not an implementation. Different implementations may behave in different ways, and we need to know which implementation you are using.

Secondly, there is an assumption that anything you write in the text content of your XML is being written because you consider it significant and want it preserved and made available to readers of your document. A CRLF (\r\n) sequence in an XML document will be reduced to LF (\n) when the document is parsed, so if the CR were not escaped as `&#xd;`, then it would be invisible to users of the document.

I guess you probably want to output the CR just so that the XML can be displayed using one of the diminishing number of editors (like Nodepad on Windows) that don't recognize LF on its own. I would suggest either (a) using a different editor to view your documents, or (b) post-processing the output to add CRLF line endings.

Comment: Exactly, I need to show it on Windows Notepad. Oh so you're suggesting to format the document as a whole like using Transformer? Is there another way? Because I need to write it in the the file formatted instead of formatting the document as a whole.

Comment: I think that most XML serialization libraries work the way you have described. You might find one that gives you control over line endings, but I don't know of one off-hand.